# Google Colab randomly connects to local directory

Tags: runtime, google-colaboratory

In google collaboratory, I am using their image classification program to train my own data. I have purchased the pro version to increase runtime duration, however, I find my runtime randomly connects to my local directory randomly. Below you can see the application logs before the runtime disconnected. It seems to start a new kernel once it connects to my local directory which crashes my runtime. Any ideas on how to solve this is greatly appreciated

[image]